# File conversion and removing special characters from a file in Linux

Tags: linux, csv, sed, awk, file-format

I have a .CSV file when I check for the special characters in the file using the command **`cat -vet filename.csv`** i get very lengthy lines with **^@**, **^I^@** and **^@^M^** characters in between each alphabet in all of the records. I checked the file type by using the command

```
file filename.csv
```

I get the output as

> filename.csv: Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode English character data,
>   with very long lines, with CRLF, CR line terminators

. I have a script to remove the control M (^M) from the file, whose output returns me an error saying: **: cannot execute binary file**.

I know that ^I represent a tab. I have a script to convert ^I to comma delimited file but Can anyone help me format the file with respect to the error and also **^@**.

Comment: `dos2unix` can help you clear this file.

Comment: @fedorqui I tried dos2unix command as **`dos2unix filename.csv`** the log shows as **dos2unix: converting file filename.csv to UNIX format ...** and then I tried to check the file using the same command as earlier **`cat -vet filename.csv`** and I still see the characters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input really is UTF-16, then you should use `iconv` to convert your file from `utf16` to something less cumbersome:

```
iconv -f utf16 -t utf8 < filename.csv > filename-utf8.csv
```

But I think that `file` got that wrong because of the zero bytes (displayed as `^@`) in there.

You should have a look at your file using sth like this to be sure of the contents:

```
xxd filename.csv | less
```

or

```
od -c filename.csv | less
```

in case you don't have `xxd` installed.  This should show more accurately than `cat` what you've got there byte-by-byte.